# R lattice 3d plot: ticks disappear when changing panel border thickness

Tags: r, panel, axis, lattice

The following code using `cloud` produces a plot with tick marks as expected:

```
require(lattice)
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
scales = list(arrows=F))
```

When the panel border thickness is changed using `axis.line` within the `par.setting` argument, the border thickness gets changed but the tick marks disappear, whether or not the `tck` argument is invoked within `scales`:

```
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
scales = list(arrows=F, tck=1),
par.settings = list(
axis.line = list(lwd = 0.5)))
```

This seems to happen with other 3d functions, such as `wireframe`. Is there something I overlooked, and how could I fix this? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's a bug in the code. If you change the distance argument to make tickmarks longer and then also try to make the ticks thicker, it results in a different line type rather than thicker ticks:

```
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
       scales = list(arrows=F, distance=c(2), draw = TRUE),
       par.settings = list(axis.line = list(lwd = 3)) # Dashed lines instead of thicker
       )
```

So there seems to be some "cross talk" on the par-channels. Furthermore, if you use the `lty` parameter, you get the desired changes in tick width:

```
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
      scales = list(arrows=F, distance=c(2), draw = TRUE),
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(lty = 0.5))   # Success
      )
```

I'm guessing this also affects the wireframe function, since they are at their core very similar, just with different panel functions. (This is on  Mac's running R 2.15.3 and lattice 0.20-15 as well as in R 3.0.2 / lattice 0.20-24.)

Comment: I'm going to send a bug report to Deepayan Sarkar.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the ticks seem to disappear is because lattice is basing their thickness upon the axis.line argument.

```
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
      scales = list(arrows=F, tck=c(3), draw = TRUE),
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(lwd = 0.5))
      )
```

In the above example, I changed the tck argument to 3, but kept your lwd argument at 0.5  You can see that R has pushed out the tick labels - so they are still being rendered but appear invisible.

Now, if you run:

```
cloud(Sepal.Length ~ Petal.Length * Petal.Width, data = iris,
      scales = list(arrows=F, tck=c(3), draw = TRUE),
      par.settings = list(axis.line = list(lwd = 2))
      )
```

You see that the ticks are still there, but are being drawn in a ratio to the axis.line argument, so really - the next question is: what are you actually trying to accomplish with passing axis.line = list(lwd = 0.5)?

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply. My reason for passing axis.line = list(lwd = 0.5) is to make the figure look nicer. The original question remains.

Comment: On further thought, and related to both our questions, one can make the tick marks appear by passing `axis.line = list(col='transparent')`, which would remove the panel border altogether, and passing `col='black'` within the `scales` argument (which does not work with `axis.line = list(lwd = 0.5)` for re-establishing tick marks). I think it looks even nicer (and more like what one would submit to journals) without the extra panel border, even in the case of multiple panels. Thanks again for the discussion.