# R levelplot remove outer border (adjust plot border)

Tags: r, correlation, lattice, levelplot

I'm creating a correlation heatmap in R with levelplot (lattice).
I'd like borders between the boxes, but not along the outside since it interferes with the plot border.
How can I remove the outer borders from the boxes?

Here is my code:

```
levelplot(matrix, border="black", 
          colorkey=list(height=.25, space="right", at=seq(-1, 1, .25), cuts=7), 
          scales=list(y=(list(cex=1)), tck = c(1,0), x=list(cex=1, rot=90)),
          main="Leaf Correlations", xlab="", ylab="", 
          col.regions=scalebluered)
```

and here is what it looks like.. I don't like the double lines on the edges..

[image]

EDIT: here is a reproducible example:

```
data(mtcars)
cars.matrix <- as.matrix(mtcars[c(2:8)])
cars.corr <- cor(cars.matrix)
levelplot(cars.corr, border="black", colorkey=list(height=.25, space="right", 
          at=seq(-1, 1, .25), cuts=7), 
          scales=list(y=(list(cex=1)), tck = c(1,0), x=list(cex=1, rot=90)), 
          xlab="", ylab="")
```

Comment: Maybe remove the outer bounding box instead? My lattice is a little rusty, but maybe something like `par.settings = list(axis.line = list(lwd = 0)`, or maybe `col = "white"` perhaps.

Comment: Hmmm...that seems to remove all lines, including ticks...

Comment: Any chance you could make a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien - added an example..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK, the fix for this is simple if a bit obscure.

Just use `lattice.options()` to reset the value of `axis.padding` used for factors, changing it from its default value of 0.6 (a little padding) to 0.5 (no padding), and you should be fine:

```
lattice.options(axis.padding=list(factor=0.5))

## An example to show that this works
data(mtcars)
cars.matrix <- as.matrix(mtcars[c(2:8)])
cars.corr <- cor(cars.matrix)
levelplot(cars.corr, border="black", colorkey=list(height=.25, space="right", 
          at=seq(-1, 1, .25), cuts=7), 
          scales=list(y=(list(cex=1)), tck = c(1,0), x=list(cex=1, rot=90)), 
          xlab="", ylab="")
```

[image]

For possibly-useful-future-reference, I figured this out by taking a quick look at the code used by `prepanel.default.levelplot()`. (The various `prepanel.***` functions are responsible, among other things, for determining the coordinates and minimal area that should be allocated to each panel so that the objects to be plotted into it will all fit nicely.)

```
head(prepanel.default.levelplot, 4)

1 function (x, y, subscripts, ...)                    
2 {                                                   
3     pad <- lattice.getOption("axis.padding")$numeric
4     if (length(subscripts) > 0) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure I would have ever figured that out!
In the meantime, I discovered the corrplot library to have some excellent options and might be a better route for me to go than trying to customize levelplot for my needs.
Using my example above, this also gets me what I want:  
    `library(corrplot)
    corrplot(cars.corr, method="shade", shade.col=NA, tl.col="black",     tl.srt=45, addgrid.col="black")`

Comment: @Paul -- Understandable, though I've just added some notes that hopefully make the thought process that led me to that option a little more reproducible by you and possibly others.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of digging shows [that a lot of the par commands may not make it to Lattice package graphics](http://www.statmethods.net/advgraphs/trellis.html).  For example, par(bty = 'n')  [won't work in this levelplot example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/removing-borders-in-r-plots-for-achieving-tuftes-axis).

> Unlike base R graphs, lattice graphs are not effected by many of the options set in the par( ) function. To view the options that can be changed, look at help(xyplot). It is frequently easiest to set these options within the high level plotting functions ... you can write functions that modify the rendering of panels.

Try passing the axis color directly into the graphic ala the method suggested by [Yangchen Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2895527/yangchen-lin) here: [R lattice 3d plot: ticks disappear when changing panel border thickness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454607/r-lattice-3d-plot-ticks-disappear-when-changing-panel-border-thickness)

```
axis.line = list(col='transparent')
```

Comment: Don't know whether it works in this specific instance, but the full option to get rid of the axis lines would be `par.settings=list(axis.line=list(col="transparent"))`.